# Convert date from MM/YY to MMYY format in xslt

Tags: xslt

How can we convert the date format from MM/ YY to MMYY in xslt?

I tried with below code:

```
 <xsl:variable name="dt" select="Guarantee/expiryDate"/>                                                                                                                          
 <xsl:value-of select="concat( substring($dt,1,2),substring($dt, 3, 2))"/>
```

Comment: would `translate(Guarantee/expiryDate, '/', '')` work?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail in your question to explain the problem you are having with your existing code. Are you getting no output, or is the output you are getting different from what you expect? Thanks.

Comment: The code you have shown us is correct. The problem is therefore in code that you haven't shown us.